# Python Include char every x positions

Tags: python, string

I want to include a char every 2 positions, to be specific, I have a MAC address this way: 00ffabcafe4c and I want it to be 00:ff:ab:ca:fe:4c

Any idea¿? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
x="00ffabcafe4c"
print re.sub(r"(\w{2}(?!$))",r"\1:",x)
```

Output:`00:ff:ab:ca:fe:4c`